# Windos 8 Html5 & Javascript: Label AppbarCommand in snapped view

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime, winjs

Developing an App for Windows 8 with HTML5 and JavaScript, I am trying to show the appbarcommand label of the appbar in snapped view.

As I had found in [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx)  it sais:

*"Windows automatically hides labels and adjusts padding for you when people snap your App"*

A workaround I had thought is to add a span with the text I want to show, but I think it is a Little tricky.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override the style that `ui-light/ui-dark.css` sets in snapped mode, so that it doesn't hide the label.

You should be able to derive this by looking at the text in DOM Explorer while the app is snapped, and seeing the CSS rule that is applying.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something similar but I was obfuscated, the correct css is: button.win-command .win-label
    {
        display: block;
    }